# Replace checksum with asymetric hash

Tags: hash, hmac, crc

The purpose is for a server to ensure the content of the flash memory of a slave IoT contains a good known firmware.

1. The server does not have a copy of the IoT firmware code - but only a hash or equivalent.
2. The server transmits a nonce/seed random key to the IoT to perform the hash computation.
3. The IoT computes a new hash using the nonce/seed - it cannot predict the answer.
4. The IoT transmits the computed hash result.
5. The server, using the nonce/seed and reference hash is able to compute the expected value.

Would anyone have a lead to the crypto function to do this?
The challenge is for the server to compute a random HASH or MAC based on a digest only, which the client cannot guess.

Comment: I presume the server does not trust the IoT device. As stated, I think this is impossible.  The IoT device can repeat the calculation that the server is going to perform, and send back the value of _that_ calculation (rather than performing a MAC of the firmware).

Comment: If the IoT firmware has been patched with malware, the malware can just keep a copy of the pre-patched parts of the firmware, and perform any necessary calculation on an emulation of the unpatched version of its firmware.

Comment: Even if the server has the full firmware, this is still impossible securely. It's feasible that the IoT has a rogue firmware, and a diff of the original and real firmware, perhaps compressed. Using data compression, that can fit the original.

Answer (score 1):

> Would anyone have a lead to the crypto function to do this? The challenge is for the server to compute a random HASH or MAC based on a digest only, which the client cannot guess.

Well, as some of the comments point out, the best we can do is prove that the firmware knows the correct image; not that it is actually running it.

However, I'll proceed ignoring that detail.

It doesn't look doable using symmetric crypto; the value $MAC(key, image)$ can only be computed with knowledge of the image, hence the server (who doesn't know the image) cannot verify it.  I suppose that the server could have a number of precomputed $key, MAC(key, image)$ pairs; however that works only so many times (depending on the number of precomputed pairs).

On the other hand, it is a solvable problem using asymmetric crypto; here is a protocol that solves it (albeit in a way that is likely too expensive to be usable in practice) - this will show that this is a solvable problem (with the above caveat):

- The IoT and the server share a value $n$, which is an integer of secret factorization.
- The server transmit a challenge value $g$
- The IoT translates the image into a (large) integer $i$ (so that if the image consists of 10kbyte = 80kbits, we have $i$ as an 80,000 bit integer); he computes $g^i \bmod n$ and sends that value to the server
- The server has a precomputed $j = i \bmod \phi(n)$ stored; he computes $g^j \bmod n$ and compares that to the value that the IoT sends

The trick this uses is that the server has a summarized version of the image $i \bmod \phi(n)$; however the IoT cannot compute that summarized version (because he doesn't know the factorization of $n$); so he needs the entire image to compute it.